# MySQL said: #1064 - MySQL trigger syntax error

Tags: mysql

This is one trigger i tried to create in phpmyadmin, mysql.

```
 BEGIN
    
    IF NEW.col_paid == 9 AND  CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 31 DAY > OLD.col_sub_date THEN
    
    UPDATE tbl_clientdata SET col_count=2;
    
    END IF;
    
    END
```

and getting the following error

> MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near '== 9 AND CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 31 DAY >
> OLD.col_sub_date THEN UPDATE tbl_c' at line 3

Comment: What's the 'trigger'

Comment: Use `=`. There is no `==` in MySQL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html

Comment: null safe equal in mysql is <=>

Answer (score 0):

Accepting the answer provided by @juergen in the comment

> Use `=`. There is no `==` in MySQL: